# Android: runOnUiThread mixing up output

Tags: java, android

I use a Process to run a native binary. That is not problem, and i can get the InputStream as normal and parse it via a Scanner. If i do `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` and inside `System.out.println(scanner.nextLine())`, everything is fine. If I run `System.out.println(scanner.nextLine())` inside `runOnUiThread()`, then it mixes up my output, i dont get everything, but what i get 20 times the same line (not the same number every run).

Here, my complete code:

```
processScanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while(processScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  line = processScanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println(line);
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          cuberiteSTDOUT.writeString(line);
      }
  });
}
```

creates normal output.

---

```
processScanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while(processScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  line = processScanner.nextLine();
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println(line);
          cuberiteSTDOUT.writeString(line);
      }
  });
}
```

creates crazy output like

```
02-28 12:44:18.433 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.435 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.441 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.442 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.443 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.447 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.449 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.450 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.450 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.451 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.452 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.453 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.454 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
02-28 12:44:18.456 30908-30908/org.cuberite.android I/System.out: Log: [3d7cb4f2|11:44:18] Created arrow 182 with speed {0.00, 0.00, 0.00} and rot {0.00, 0.00}
```

(which is just some lines repeated but others left out)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre line is manipulated in another thread than it is printed.
Change the line to:

```
final String line = processScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it.... any further explanation? ( i can accept only in 5 minutes -.-)

Comment: First the 2 Threads had a reference to the line variable. Now this variable is temporary and only the ui-thread can access after assignment.